# KendoUI NumericTextBox doesn't hold values right

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

Using a `Kendo UI` numeric text box, I am having an issue with getting it to retain the number given between clicks. Here is my example...

```
<input id="${Statistic.Name}-size"
    type="number"
    value="30"
    class="dark"
    style="width: 100px; float: left;"
    data-bind="value: Measurement"
    data-role="numerictextbox"
    data-decimals="5"
    data-step="0.001" />
```

The numeric text box is formatted exactly how I want, but if I type in "0.005", then I click somewhere else, the text box changes to "0.01".

However if I click on it again, it changes back to 0.005, and then back to 0.01 when I click elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`format` property](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox#configuration-format) to an appropriate [format string](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting) which can display more than two decimal digits.

Something like:

```
data-format="0.#####"
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbK8y/).

Comment: Oh! That's perfect, yes, that works. Thank you, I was having a lot of trouble with this one.

Comment: how to dynamically update format using button click or something?